# GEE Error: "Layer 1: Tile error: Array: Max (NaN) cannot be less than min (NaN)."

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have run PCA on some vegetation and texture indexes obtained from GEE sentinel-2. And successfully selected the first three bands of the final PCA, but I couldn't add them to the map (or export them to the drive).This is my code：
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2FLiLiy%2Ffresh%3Apcaimage

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}
var composite = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2021-07-01','2021-12-31')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',5))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
// print(composite)
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-106.11453359316594, 39.158962205168855],
          [-106.11453359316594, 35.741091171129625],
          [-97.06179921816594, 35.741091171129625],
          [-97.06179921816594, 39.158962205168855]]], null, false);
var boundary = geometry;
var dataset = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');
var elevation = dataset.select('elevation').clip(geometry).float();
  var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation);
  var aspect = ee.Terrain.aspect(elevation);
  var hillshade = ee.Terrain.hillshade(elevation,315,45);
  
  var add_RS_index = function(img){
var ndti = img.expression('(SWIR1-SWIR2)/(SWIR1+SWIR2)',{
    'SWIR1': img.select('B11'),
    'SWIR2':img.select('B12'),
}).float().rename('NDTI').copyProperties(img,['system_start']);
  return img.addBands([ndti]);
};

var composite = composite.map(add_RS_index); 
var bands=['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B11','B12','NDTI']
var im = composite.mean().select('B8A').toUint16();
var textureS2 =im.glcmTexture({size:3})
print('textureS2',textureS2)
var ndti = composite.mean().select('NDTI').toUint16();
var textureS3 =ndti.glcmTexture({size:3})
print('textureS3',textureS3)
  var composite1 = composite.mean().select(bands)
                         .addBands(textureS2)
                         .addBands(textureS3)
                         .addBands(elevation)
                         .addBands(slope)
                         .addBands(aspect)
                         .addBands(hillshade)
print('composite1',composite1)

function PCA(maskedImage){
  var image = maskedImage.unmask()
  var scale = 400;
  var region = boundary;
  var bandNames = image.bandNames();
  // Mean center the data to enable a faster covariance reducer
  // and an SD stretch of the principal components.
  var meanDict = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    bestEffort: true,
     tileScale: 16
  });
  var means = ee.Image.constant(meanDict.values(bandNames));
  var centered = image.subtract(means);
  // This helper function returns a list of new band names.
  var getNewBandNames = function(prefix) {
    var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, bandNames.length());
    return seq.map(function(b) {
      return ee.String(prefix).cat(ee.Number(b).int());
    });
  };
  // This function accepts mean centered imagery, a scale and
  // a region in which to perform the analysis.  It returns the
  // Principal Components (PC) in the region as a new image.
  var getPrincipalComponents = function(centered, scale, region) {
    // Collapse the bands of the image into a 1D array per pixel.
    var arrays = centered.toArray();
    
    // Compute the covariance of the bands within the region.
    var covar = arrays.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance(),
      geometry: region,
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 1e13,
      bestEffort: true,
      tileScale: 16
    });
     // Get the 'array' covariance result and cast to an array.
    // This represents the band-to-band covariance within the region.
    var covarArray = ee.Array(covar.get('array'));

    // Perform an eigen analysis and slice apart the values and vectors.
    var eigens = covarArray.eigen();

    // This is a P-length vector of Eigenvalues.
    var eigenValues = eigens.slice(1, 0, 1);
    // Compute Percentage Variance of each component
    var eigenValuesList = eigenValues.toList().flatten()
    var total = eigenValuesList.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
    var percentageVariance = eigenValuesList.map(function(item) {
      return (ee.Number(item).divide(total)).multiply(100).format('%.2f')
    })
    // This will allow us to decide how many components capture
    // most of the variance in the input
    print('Percentage Variance of Each Component', percentageVariance)
    // This is a PxP matrix with eigenvectors in rows.
    var eigenVectors = eigens.slice(1, 1);
    // Convert the array image to 2D arrays for matrix computations.
    var arrayImage = arrays.toArray(1);

    // Left multiply the image array by the matrix of eigenvectors.
    var principalComponents = ee.Image(eigenVectors).matrixMultiply(arrayImage);
        // Turn the square roots of the Eigenvalues into a P-band image.
    var sdImage = ee.Image(eigenValues.sqrt())
      .arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('sd')]);

    // Turn the PCs into a P-band image, normalized by SD.
    return principalComponents
      // Throw out an an unneeded dimension, [[]] -> [].
      .arrayProject([0])
      // Make the one band array image a multi-band image, [] -> image.
      .arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')])
      // Normalize the PCs by their SDs.
      .divide(sdImage);
  };
  var pcImage = getPrincipalComponents(centered, scale, region);
  return pcImage.mask(maskedImage.mask());
}
var pca = PCA(composite1).select(['pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3']);
// var composite = composite.addBands(pca);  
print('pca',pca)

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["B4","B3","B2"],
                     "min":0.03596875071525574,
                     "max":0.25026053190231323,
                     "gamma":1};
                     
Map.centerObject(geometry, 8);
Map.addLayer(pca.clip(geometry), {bands: ['pc3', 'pc2', 'pc1']}, 'pca')
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: pca,
  description: 'PAC',
  folder:'pca',
  scale: 10,
  region:geometry,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
```

Comment: looks like you have nan values in your data which is outside of your min and max imageparams. you'll need to find a way to locate and mask these

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the value of tileScale, maybe this is the solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your `textureS2` and `textureS3` images. Bellow is your code but without using `textureS2` and `textureS3`. You can see that now it seems to work.

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}
var composite = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2021-07-01','2021-12-31')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',5))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
// print(composite)
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-106.11453359316594, 39.158962205168855],
          [-106.11453359316594, 35.741091171129625],
          [-97.06179921816594, 35.741091171129625],
          [-97.06179921816594, 39.158962205168855]]], null, false);
var boundary = geometry;
var dataset = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');
var elevation = dataset.select('elevation').clip(geometry).float();
  var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation);
  var aspect = ee.Terrain.aspect(elevation);
  var hillshade = ee.Terrain.hillshade(elevation,315,45);
  
  var add_RS_index = function(img){
var ndti = img.expression('(SWIR1-SWIR2)/(SWIR1+SWIR2)',{
    'SWIR1': img.select('B11'),
    'SWIR2':img.select('B12'),
}).float().rename('NDTI').copyProperties(img,['system_start']);
  return img.addBands([ndti]);
};

var composite = composite.map(add_RS_index); 
var bands=['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B11','B12','NDTI']
var im = composite.mean().select('B8A').toUint16();
var textureS2 =im.glcmTexture({size:3})
print('textureS2',textureS2)
var ndti = composite.mean().select('NDTI').toUint16();
var textureS3 =ndti.glcmTexture({size:3})
print('textureS3',textureS3)
  var composite1 = composite.mean().select(bands)
                        // .addBands(textureS2)
                        // .addBands(textureS3)
                        .addBands(elevation)
                        .addBands(slope)
                        .addBands(aspect)
                        .addBands(hillshade)
print('composite1',composite1)

function PCA(maskedImage){
  var image = maskedImage.unmask()
  var scale = 400;
  var region = boundary;
  var bandNames = image.bandNames();
  // Mean center the data to enable a faster covariance reducer
  // and an SD stretch of the principal components.
  var meanDict = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    bestEffort: true,
     tileScale: 16
  });
  var means = ee.Image.constant(meanDict.values(bandNames));
  var centered = image.subtract(means);
  // This helper function returns a list of new band names.
  var getNewBandNames = function(prefix) {
    var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, bandNames.length());
    return seq.map(function(b) {
      return ee.String(prefix).cat(ee.Number(b).int());
    });
  };
  // This function accepts mean centered imagery, a scale and
  // a region in which to perform the analysis.  It returns the
  // Principal Components (PC) in the region as a new image.
  var getPrincipalComponents = function(centered, scale, region) {
    // Collapse the bands of the image into a 1D array per pixel.
    var arrays = centered.toArray();
    
    // Compute the covariance of the bands within the region.
    var covar = arrays.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance(),
      geometry: region,
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 1e13,
      bestEffort: true,
      tileScale: 16
    });
     // Get the 'array' covariance result and cast to an array.
    // This represents the band-to-band covariance within the region.
    var covarArray = ee.Array(covar.get('array'));

    // Perform an eigen analysis and slice apart the values and vectors.
    var eigens = covarArray.eigen();

    // This is a P-length vector of Eigenvalues.
    var eigenValues = eigens.slice(1, 0, 1);
    // Compute Percentage Variance of each component
    var eigenValuesList = eigenValues.toList().flatten()
    var total = eigenValuesList.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
    var percentageVariance = eigenValuesList.map(function(item) {
      return (ee.Number(item).divide(total)).multiply(100).format('%.2f')
    })
    // This will allow us to decide how many components capture
    // most of the variance in the input
    print('Percentage Variance of Each Component', percentageVariance)
    // This is a PxP matrix with eigenvectors in rows.
    var eigenVectors = eigens.slice(1, 1);
    // Convert the array image to 2D arrays for matrix computations.
    var arrayImage = arrays.toArray(1);

    // Left multiply the image array by the matrix of eigenvectors.
    var principalComponents = ee.Image(eigenVectors).matrixMultiply(arrayImage);
        // Turn the square roots of the Eigenvalues into a P-band image.
    var sdImage = ee.Image(eigenValues.sqrt())
      .arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('sd')]);

    // Turn the PCs into a P-band image, normalized by SD.
    return principalComponents
      // Throw out an an unneeded dimension, [[]] -> [].
      .arrayProject([0])
      // Make the one band array image a multi-band image, [] -> image.
      .arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')])
      // Normalize the PCs by their SDs.
      .divide(sdImage);
  };
  var pcImage = getPrincipalComponents(centered, scale, region);
  return pcImage.mask(maskedImage.mask());
}
var pca = PCA(composite1).select(['pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3']);
// var composite = composite.addBands(pca);  
print('pca',pca)

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["B4","B3","B2"],
                     "min":0.03596875071525574,
                     "max":0.25026053190231323,
                     "gamma":1};
                     
Map.centerObject(geometry, 8);
Map.addLayer(pca.clip(geometry), {bands: ['pc3', 'pc2', 'pc1']}, 'pca')
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: pca,
  description: 'PAC',
  folder:'pca',
  scale: 10,
  region:geometry,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
```